Get the next Alphabet in SQL
I have a table which stores alphabets in the format A, B, C.... Z, AA, AB, AC.
Now I have currently in my table the values A and B.



Supermarket
Aisle




1
A


1
B



I want to add to more aisles to my supermarket, that is continue the inserts in the table based on the last character available.  I have managed to get the last available character from my table through:
CHAR(ASCII('A') + (SELECT MAX(ASCII(WAL_CH_AISLE)) - ASCII('A') + 1 FROM Supermarket WHERE Sup_Id = 1))
For example I want to add 3 more aisles, so I total in my table I will have:



Supermarket
Aisle




1
A


1
B


1
C


1
D


1
E



I want to do a while for the insert. Like
while C < E
However, as entry value I have a numerical value which represents the additional aisles which needs to be added.  In my example my entry value would be 3.
How can I do the comparison in the while?  How can I get the E from the 3 input value?

didn't you ask this question like 2 hours ago

Looks like, to me, @siggemannen , that they didn't give the full picture. In the other question it's strongly implied an Aisle would be a letter; now it turns out is can be 1 or more letters.

Alphabet, in which language?

Because it appears that the answer I did give on your other question was useful (as you have a snippet of the code in this question), as you new user you might want to have a read of What should I do when someone answers my question?

It would be much easier to store an int number and to convert the result to the A, B, ... AA, AB, ... notation for display only.

What's the actual problem? It's probably a lot easier to solve the actual problem than the assumed individual steps that may not have any relation to the solution anyway. For example Excel-like "numbering" like A, AA etc is done using proper numbers that get encoded for display or export. SQL Server doesn't have such encoding functions but you can precalculate and store the labels in a Numbers table indexed by the actual number, and JOIN with it. Not only will this be faster, it will allow you to propertly index, sort and filter the values

For example, your next problem will be that B comes after AZ due to lexical sorting, breaking both ordering and range searches. That's not an issue at all if you keep using integers though, and JOIN with the Numbers table on AisleNumber, eg SELECT ... , Numbers.Label as Aisle FROM ... INNER JOIN Numbers on Numbers.Num=AisleNumber

At least you could get around that problem by ordering by LEN and then value, I suppose, @PanagiotisKanavos . 'B' > 'AA', but 1 (LEN('B')) < 2 (LEN('AA')), so 1,'B' < 2,'AA'. (This is not a defence to store the letter numbering in the table without a lookup table though.)
